# How to enforce a MFA session expiry after 24 hours

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Azure AD MFA newbie here.  I have been asked to come up with MFA configuration based on a set of business rules.

One business rule is: MFA sessions will expire after 24hrs or pc shutdown, whichever comes first.

To enforce the 'expire after 24hrs' part of the business rule, I propose setting [remember multi-factor authentication > Days before a device must re-authenticate] to 1 day, and not enabling [Allow users to remember multi-factor authentication on devices they trust].  Does this sound like the correct approach?

I cannot find anywhere to enforce MFA after a pc shutdown, is there anything like that available?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

For remembered devices, you should be able to configure the **[Days before a device must re-authenticate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3124671/some-users-who-are-enabled-for-azure-multi-factor-authentication-aren)**. This option lets users who have successfully authenticated through multi-factor authentication avoid future multi-factor authentication prompts for the next 1–60 days, depending on the value that's configured.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marilee.  So if I remove the tick from (Allow users to remember multi-factor authentication on devices they trust), would this automatically set the days before re-authenticate to (1) day?